# multiple values in string dataframe python

Tags: python

i want to ask how to split column **Name** which has multiple values into new columns that represent each value.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Name': ['Bird,Elephant,Dog,Cat', 'Bird,Elephant,Dog', 'Bird,Elephant,none,Cat', 
'Bird'],
'Age': [20, 21, 19, 18]}  
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 
df
```

the output :

| Name | Count |
| --- | --- |
| Bird,Elephant,Dog,Cat | 34 |
| Bird,Elephant,Dog | 42 |
| Bird,Elephant,none,Cat | 20 |
| Bird | 5 |

i try use this code :

```
merge_tol=df['Name'].str.split(',', expand=True)
```

but it just separate for each string, not the values.

desirable output is (kindof or you have better suggestion):

| Name | Age | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bird,Elephant,Dog,Cat | 20 | Bird | Elephant | Dog | Cat |
| Bird,Elephant,Dog | 21 | Bird | Elephant | Dog | NAN |
| Bird,Elephant,none,Cat | 19 | Bird | Elephant | none | Cat |
| Bird | 18 | Bird | Nan | NAN | NAN |

actually the goal is **i want to visualize by countplot/else for each value to get what most favorite name and so on**. for this example case is Bird = 4 count and so on.

kindly help, thanks !

Comment: df.join(merge_tol)

Comment: @scccboom i expect to split the values into new columns instead of join

Comment: Try it and display output.

Comment: @scccboom , why not showing when i use df[0].unique() ?

Comment: `join` return new DataFrame, so `df = df.join(merge_tol)` or `new_df = df.join(merge_tol)`

Comment: @scccboom, it works for this example case but it doesnt work in the real case (https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/parisrohan/credit-score-classification?select=train.csv,  you can see in the train.csv dataset and column 'Type_of_Loan'). i dont know if i'm missing something. kindly help, thanks

Comment: @scccboom the issue when i call e.g [0] for value_counts, there are still showing another value instead of e.g Elephant, none. It's still showing Bird, Elephant, none :(

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd


data = {'Name': ['Bird,Elephant,Dog,Cat', 'Bird,Elephant,Dog', 'Bird,Elephant,none,Cat', 
'Bird'],
'Age': [20, 21, 19, 18]}  
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 
new_df = df.join(df.Name.str.split(',', expand=True).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True).rename('NewName'))
print(new_df["NewName"].value_counts())
```

Comment: it works for this example case but it doesnt work in the real case (kaggle.com/datasets/parisrohan/…, you can see in the train.csv dataset and column 'Type_of_Loan'). i dont know if i'm missing something. kindly help, thanks

Comment: @Amelia Putri Damayanti
 This should be a new question, and 'it dosn't work' without any help. You should describe the actual output and your expected output in new question, like this question.